# What counts as disclosing source for software licenses?

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl, source-code, mpl

MPL v2, GPL v3 and other licenses alike require giving users access to source code.

1. For desktop applications - does access have to be provided through the user interface (GUI)? Or can it just be through program files?
2. For mobile apps - is listing the names of libraries in-use sufficient? I have seen apps do this with MPL v2 licensed libraries without providing hyperlinks to the source; are users expected to look up the names?
3. For code hosted on a CDN - how do end users know what the hosted content is licensed under in the first place? Does the same license automatically apply to the hosting provider (since the code was 'distributed' to them first)? And if it does, is the hosting provider solely responsible for releasing source code to the end user?
4. For code embedded in hardware - in hardware such as game consoles, screen readers and airplane entertainment systems where 'tinkering' is limited, how would GPL'd code be given to the user, if at all? In the case of assistive technology, does accessibility have to be taken into consideration?

Note: I understand how MPL is a file-level copyleft while GPL applies to the entire codebase. I would like to ask for the method of disclosing source, not the scope. A similar question was asked [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/how-to-disclose-source-of-a-software-with-mozilla-public-licence) but the answer did not cover details of the method.

Comment: It would help if you could explain which *precise* portions, sentences, and words of GPLv3 section 6 you have trouble understanding, which research you have done to understand those, why you failed, and what you tried to remedy that situation. That way, you save the answerers a lot of time and effort and avoid them explaining things you already know, or explaining things in terms you already researched and didn't understand.

Comment: Did you read the license? It should tell you.

Comment: I have read both of the above mentioned licenses several times and understand their terms. The licenses lack examples however, which is why I asked this question with reference to specific cases.

Comment: Generally speaking, you have to make your derivative work available, and you have make it available under the original license and copyright, plus any additional *compatible* license/copyright you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IANAL or even play one on TV

From my understanding while you have to be able to produced your modified code to anyone who requests it, there is no restriction on how you do that (and that you can even charge for the media that it is supplied on if a physical copy is provided.)

This [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/280703/155433) points to [A Practical Guide to GPL Compliance](https://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2008/compliance-guide.html) which suggests several methods for distribution which includes things like (for GPLv2 code, and insertion in printed materials for your product)

> The software included in this product contains copyrighted software
> that is licensed under the GPL. A copy of that license is included in
> this document on page X. You may obtain the complete Corresponding
> Source code from us for a period of three years after our last
> shipment of this product, which will be no earlier than 2011-08-01, by
> sending a money order or check for $5 to:  GPL Compliance Division
> Our Company  Any Town, US 99999
>
> Please write “source for product Y ” in the memo line of your payment.
>
> You may also find a copy of the source at
> http://www.example.com/sources/Y/.
>
> This offer is valid to anyone in receipt of this information.

So you do not need to widely distribute your modifications on some public facing website, and as long as there is *some* mechanism to obtain the modified code then you are probably complying with the spirit of your preferred license!

As an additional resource, there is also [Frequently Asked Questions about the GNU Licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html) which has a a complete section called "Distribution of programs released under the GNU licenses" (of which there is too much to quote here)